# Multiple values for a sas macro parameter

Tags: macros, sas

I'm new to SAS Macro programming and need to enable the following macro to be able to handle and process multiple values for its macro parameters.Hello,

```
data have;
input name $ ACCOUNT_ID $ cust_id;
cards;
ARTHUR CC1234 1234
TOM eil1235 1235
MIKEZ tb1236 1236
MATT mb1237 1237
LIZ TB1238 1238
PIZ VB1239 1239
TAN MB1240 1240
PANDA . 1241
;
run;

%MACRO algo (IN_DS=,VAR_LIST=,DATA_TYPE_LIST=,OUT_DS=);
DATA &OUT_DS;
SET &IN_DS;

%If &data_type_LIST = num %then 
&var_LIST=sum(&VAR_LIST,2);
%else &var_LIST=cats(&var_LIST,'re');;
run;
%mend;

%algo(IN_DS=HAVE,VAR_LIST=CUST_ID,DATA_TYPE_LIST=num,OUT_DS=out1);`
```

I now need to enable this macro to be able to pass multiple values for the macro parameters. Something like this :

`%algo(IN_DS=HAVE,VAR_LIST='CUST_ID,ACCT_ID',DATA_TYPE_LIST='num,char',OUT_DS=out1);`
Can someone help me enable this functionality in the macro code.

Comment: You cannot do this: `&var_LIST=cats(&var_LIST,'re');;` because that would generate the code as `var1, var2 = cats(var1, var2, 're');;` which is invalid SAS syntax. Please explain further what you're trying to do here. In general, I recommend not doing this and using a space delimited list which has no issues. Comma delimited lists to the macro are what causes you issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the macro can handle multiple values.  In general it is not a good idea to use comma as the delimiter in your list of values when calling a macro.

Usually space is the best delimiter since then you can use the macro value directly in the generated code.  For example if your variables are all of the same type you can just use data step ARRAY.

```
%MACRO algo (IN_DS=,VAR_LIST=,DATA_TYPE_LIST=,OUT_DS=);
DATA &OUT_DS;
  SET &IN_DS;
  array list &var_list ;
  do _n_=1 to dim(list);
%if &data_type_LIST = num %then %do ;
    list(_n_)=sum(list(_n_),2);
%end;
%else %do;
    list(_n_)=cats(list(_n_),'re');
%end;
  end;
run;
%mend algo;
```

If your variables are NOT all of the same type then you need to generate a separate statement for each variable. In that case you can use a different delimiter if you want, like a pipe character, that is easier to use as delimiter in calls to macro functions like `%scan()`.

```
%MACRO algo (IN_DS=,VAR_LIST=,DATA_TYPE_LIST=,OUT_DS=);
%local i var;
DATA &OUT_DS;
  SET &IN_DS;
  %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&var_list,|));
    %let var=%scan(&var_list,&i,|);
    %if %scan(&data_type_LIST,&i,|) = num %then %do ;
  &var=sum(&var,2);
    %end;
    %else %do;
  &var=cats(&var,'re');
    %end;
  %end;
run;
%mend algo;
%algo(IN_DS=HAVE,VAR_LIST=CUST_ID|ACCT_ID,DATA_TYPE_LIST=num|char,OUT_DS=out1);
```

Comment: I can't do this since the columns that I need to execute the code on are not the same data type. Like in the example I gave above, one is numeric and other is char column.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, please clarify.  Your posted code has only one parameter for variable type.  Are you saying it is also a list of variable types?  If so then instead of a data step ARRAY you will need to have a macro `%DO` loop to process each variable separately.  Still no need to use commas in the macro call.

Comment: Yes, as I had posted in my initial post, I want to process a code multiple times for multiple values for its parameters. As I had clearly given in the example where I specified what I am trying to achieve `%algo(IN_DS=HAVE,VAR_LIST='CUST_ID,ACCT_ID',DATA_TYPE_LIST='num,char',OUT_DS=out1); ` If you see the macro parms VAR_LIST and DATA_TYPE_LIST both have multiple values and the columns passed in VAR_LIST are of different datatypes, as shown in the sample dataset as well.

Comment: Updated answer to include example that can handle that.

Comment: It worked, I was actually trying the same thing but did not treat the counter var "I" as macro var and was using %scan(&var_list,i,|) instead of &i. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter argument should be macro quoted with %STR() in the macro invocation.

Try

```
%algo 
( IN_DS=HAVE
, VAR_LIST= %STR (CUST_ID, ACCT_ID)
, DATA_TYPE_LIST=num
, OUT_DS=out1
);
```

Macro quoting is different than DATA step quoting used for character literals.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a list of variables and then use that list in the code you posted above, my suggestion would be to treat the &var_list as a list, and use scan to determine how many variables there are, and then loop through the list and execute the code accordingly.

Comment: Can you show how to do that, that is exactly what I have been trying to achieve but coulnd't.